# How to allow only one line break with Laravel

Tags: php

I'm using Laravel 5.2, but i have problem with line breaks when someone post ($post->content) an article, i want to allow him to make just one line break after a paragraph.

problem:

```
[line break]
[line break]
[line break]
Some text
[line break]
[line break]
some some text
```

i want to make it:

```
Some text
[line break]
some some text
```

Comment: [preg_repalace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) would be the obvious start

Comment: @Dagon tear it down and build a new palace.

Comment: explain more pls and share the code you are already using

Comment: This is not a Laravel-specific question, perhaps it's better to remove 'laravel' tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !
first i removed all the line breaks that the string start with, and then i replace all the other line breaks with only one line break.

```
$remove_first_spaces = preg_replace('/^(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/', '', nl2br($request->content));
$remove_multiple_spaces = preg_replace("#(<br */?>\s*)+#i", "<br />", $remove_first_spaces);
$clean_content = $remove_multiple_spaces;
```